# Image resize inside of an anchor tag

Tags: css, next.js

I'm currently trying to style a page in NextJS. I have an image inside an anchor inside a div. I want to resize the image but no matter what I try, it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried applying properties to all three elements, each one individually, and two at a time.

The relevant code:

```
          <div className={styles.projectContainer}> 

            <div className={styles.projectDescriptionContainer}>
              <h3>Title</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum etc..</p>
            </div>

            <div className={styles.projectPhotoContainer}>
              <a className={styles.projectLink}
              href="heroku link"
              target="_blank">
              <img src='/local-file.png' />
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>
```

```
.projectContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
}

.projectDescriptionContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 10vh;
}

.projectPhotoContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vh;
}

.projectLink {
  display: inline-block;
}

.img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The link does not have any width size. add:

```
.projectLink {
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

Also, Your `object-fit: cover;` needs a height. `auto` won't work

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I added your suggested CSS properties, and I also set height to a random 10% just to get a value in there.

However, it didn't have any impact on the page.

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem with the html your Nextjs reproduce and css in a platform as jsfiddle or codepen. and post it here if you have same problem. Probably you won't and you'll find the problem by yourself... There may be some css classes not correctly called

Answer (score 0):

Right, it's been a while this question has been asked, since I was in same situation few days ago and figured this out, I just wanna share it.

You have to work on the anchor tag, make sure to add the inline CSS code:

```
<a href="example"  style="width:100%;" >example- image is here</a>
```

It will work mate!